# How do I access the falloff option on a bulge deformer

Tags: animation, cinema-4d

I am following a 4D cinema tutorial that requires me to use the bulge transformer. One of the steps wants me to use this falloff option that bulge deformer had in it older version.

I tried searching for it in the bulge deformer option but I have not found anything called falloff. The area it used to be in has been replaced with something called fields.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.